# JDO Java Data Objects example

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, jdo

can someone help me to find a step-by-step example for developing JDO in a gwt project?

I really want to know and learn the jdo and differences between that and jpa

RGDS

Comment: http://db.apache.org/jdo/jdo_v_jpa.html

Comment: I'm sure doing a web search would reveal many docs for JDO itself, and JDO with GWT, never mind JDO .v. JPA. But then you don't seem to have done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used both jdo and jpa. I find it much easier using jpa for my work. If you are using datanucleus then you should look at the documentation on app engine located below.

JDO
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2

JPA
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2

These are the newer specs for app engine and if you are not using these then just about any database should be fairly straight forward.

I personally use jpa, request factory, service locators and a Dao pattern for accessing my objects. Here is something I posted earlier that has some code samples that may help. If you are not using app engine then a normal Long key should be easier.

[GAE Datastore with GWT, making more friendly/smaller keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952874/gae-datastore-with-gwt-making-more-friendly-smaller-keys)

You should also look at using a Servlet Filter for handling your EntityManager so that requestfactory can handle fetching your object graph using the .with("childGetterMethod") clause. This will save you quite a bit of coding to fetch child entities while the servlet filter handles opening and closing your entity manager.